# Circumventing F expression problem of django-simple-history by overriding save

Tags: django, django-signals, django-simple-history

Django-simple-history is inserting new record on each save of target model. In [docs](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/common_issues.html#using-f-expressions) the problem with F expressions is described. I try to circumvent this with overriden save method.

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
       # some other actions
       self.refresh_from_db()
```

But it seems, that this is not working. Is the `post_save` signal of base model called directly after `super().save()` call? If so, is there a way to solve this problem keeping the F expression in target model update?

UPDATE: Saved instance has one of its attributes defined using an F expression, so this code is called in some other module:

```
   instance.some_attribute = (F('some_attribute') + 15)
   instance.save(update_fields=['some_attribute'])
```

This throws an error in django-simple-history's `post_save` signal, when it tries to insert a extended copy of `instance` to history table. I tried to refresh the instance in overriden `save` method to get rid of the F expression in `some_attribute` so the actual value is loaded. From the traceback it seems that the `post_save` is called right after `super().save()` call, before the refresh. Is it the way Django post_save with overriden save works? If so, is there a way to not change the update code (leave the update with F expression) and solve the history insert in model's save?

Comment: can you elaborate further what are you trying to achieve, like expanding your code segment with relevant f expression etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-simple-history` provides signals for before and after the historical record is created: https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.0/signals.html

I suggest using these to update the instance before it gets saved to the historical table. Something like this should work:

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from simple_history.signals import (
    pre_create_historical_record,
    post_create_historical_record
)

@receiver(pre_create_historical_record)
def pre_create_historical_record_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs["instance"]
    history_instance = kwargs["history_instance"]
        if isinstance(instance, ModelYouWantToRefresh)
    instance.refresh_from_db()
    history_instance.some_attribute = instance.some_attribute
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on Ross Mechanic answer I made a universal solution

```
from django import dispatch
from django.db.models import expressions
from simple_history import signals


@dispatch.receiver(
    signals.pre_create_historical_record, dispatch_uid="simple_history_refresh"
)
def remove_f_expressions(sender, instance, history_instance, **kwargs) -> None:  # noqa
    f_expression_fields = []

    for field in history_instance._meta.fields:  # noqa
        field_value = getattr(history_instance, field.name)
        if isinstance(field_value, expressions.BaseExpression):
            f_expression_fields.append(field.name)

    if f_expression_fields:
        instance.refresh_from_db()
        for field_name in f_expression_fields:
            field_value = getattr(instance, field_name)
            setattr(history_instance, field_name, field_value)
```